# How to display column vector x in Cramer's rule in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to code the Cramer's Rule on MATLAB for a square matrix. I understand the Rule perfectly and also believe the logic behind my code is alright. However, could you please check where I might be going wrong that my result is not being displayed correctly? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

```
function x = cramer(A, b)

r = size(A, 1);
c = size(A, 2);
n = size(b, 1);


if r ~= c
    disp('Oops! Please enter a square matrix');
end 

if r == c == n

D = det(A);

if D == 0
    disp('Oops! Either, there are a family of soultions or no unique solution')
end

if D ~= 0 

result = zeros(n, 1);


        for (i = 1:n)
        A_x = A;
        A_x(:, i) = b;
        Dx = det(A_x);
        result(i,1) = Dx/D;

        end

        x = result;
end

end 



end
```

Comment: When you say *"my result is not being displayed correctly"*  it'd be helpful to show an example.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `if r == c == n` check. 
The expression `r == c == n` can be expanded as `(r == c) == n`
So it compares the value of `logical(r == c)` with `n`.

As an example:

```
>> 2 == 2 == 1

ans =

logical

1
```

Rewrite your check as `r == c && c == n` or `isequal(r,c,n)` and you should be good.

EDIT: You can simplify your logic quite some, say for example by:

```
function x = cramers(A, b)

if diff(size(A)) && size(A,1) == n

    D = det(A);

    if D == 0
        disp('Oops! Either, there are a family of solutions or no unique solution')
        return
    else
        result = zeros(n, 1);


        for i = 1:n
            A_x = A;
            A_x(:, i) = b;
            Dx = det(A_x);
            result(i,1) = Dx/D;

        end

        x = result;
    end
else
    disp('Dimension error')
    return
end
end
```

Comment: Yes, now it works for a square matrix A and a column vector b with the same rows as columns of A. However, if I input a column vector b with rows not equal to columns of A, an error message regarding x not being assigned is displayed. What is up with that?

Comment: I would suggest you step through your code with the debugger to better understand where your logic fails.
Basically, when the check fails, it does not ever reach the `x = result` assignment, and hence the interpreter throws the error you see.

Comment: ohh alright! thanks so much! I solved the problem by giving a further else statement and then giving another x = [] to return nothing

Comment: Check out my edited answer, you can make your logic much simpler.